# How to set border for a pie chart in Sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

Hi anybody knows how to set the border for a pie chart in sencha touch? I tried every configuration in the docs but had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chart series are drawn using [sprites](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.draw.sprite.Sprite). You can pass custom sprite attributes through the [`subStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-subStyle) option of the serie. See the doc of sprite (and CSS canvas properties) for available property.

Note that the `subStyle` option expects an array of values that will be used in order for each records.

Given all that, we can add borders to the [docs pie chart example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie) this way:

```
var chart = new Ext.chart.PolarChart({
    animate: true,
    interactions: ['rotate'],
    colors: ['#115fa6', '#94ae0a', '#a61120', '#ff8809', '#ffd13e'],
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
        data: [
            {name: 'metric one',   data1: 10, data2: 12, data3: 14, data4: 8,  data5: 13},
            {name: 'metric two',   data1: 7,  data2: 8,  data3: 16, data4: 10, data5: 3},
            {name: 'metric three', data1: 5,  data2: 2,  data3: 14, data4: 12, data5: 7},
            {name: 'metric four',  data1: 2,  data2: 14, data3: 6,  data4: 1,  data5: 23},
            {name: 'metric five',  data1: 27, data2: 38, data3: 36, data4: 13, data5: 33}
        ]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        label: {
            field: 'name',
            display: 'rotate'
        },
        xField: 'data3',
        donut: 30,

        // --- Modification Here! ---

        subStyle: {
            strokeStyle: ['black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black'],
            lineWidth: [2,2,2,2,2]
        }

        // ---

    }]
});
Ext.Viewport.setLayout('fit');
Ext.Viewport.add(chart);
```

Adding border only to the external part of the chart would be much more complicated, I think.